# jq: Comparing three files to find missing identifiers in any

Tags: jq

I have 3 different files. `mongo.json`, `elastic.json`, `stripe.json`.

Each one has an array of clients and I want to compare the lenght of those arrays to check if they have the same amount of customers for preventing errors. Here's an example of each file:

`Mongo.json`

```
[{
    "_id": {
            "$oid": "59c3942baeef22b03fa573d2"
    },
    "client_id": "test@test.com",
    "name": "Windows Client"
},{
    "_id": {
            "$oid": "59c3942baeef22b03fa573d2"
    },
    "client_id": "test2@test2.com",
    "name": "Linux Client"
}]
```

`elastic.json`

```
[
    {
        "alias" : "test@test.com",
        "index" : "index1",
        "filter" : "-"
    },
    {
        "alias" : "test2@test2.com",
        "index" : "index2",
        "filter" : "-"
    }
]
```

`stripe.json`

```
{
"object": "list",
"data": [
  {
      "id": "test@test.com",
      "object": "customer",
      "account_balance": 0,
      "created": 1505990903
  }
]
}
```

With the following command I obtain the lenght of each array, but I don't know how to compare these lengts for check if they are the same or not:

```
jq '. | length' mongo.json elastic.json stripe.json
```

result:

```
2
2
1
```

How I can compare these results? I would like the following output:

In case they have the same length:

```
Everyting is OK.
```

In contrary case:

```
Missing customer test2@test2.com
```

The customer ID: **is the email**.

How I can do that?

Comment: I've reduced the amount of data and explained a little bit more what I want.

Comment: That's definitely much better now.

Comment: I was fixing it right now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: BTW, short-circuiting and assuming everything is okay if the lengths all match is not a great idea -- what if mongo or ES has one item present that's in neither of the other data stores **and** one item missing that's in both the other stores? The total length is the same, but the result isn't everything being in sync.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jq -n \
  --slurpfile mongo mongo.json \
  --slurpfile elastic elastic.json \
  --slurpfile stripe stripe.json \
'
  [$mongo[][].client_id] as $mongo_ids
| [$elastic[][].alias] as $elastic_ids
| [$stripe[].data[].id] as $stripe_ids
| (($mongo_ids + $elastic_ids + $stripe_ids) | unique) as $all_ids
| {"missing_from_stripe":  ($all_ids - $stripe_ids),
   "missing_from_elastic": ($all_ids - $elastic_ids),
   "missing_from_mongo":   ($all_ids - $mongo_ids)}
| [to_entries[] | select(.value|length > 0)] | from_entries
'
```

...correctly emits:

```
{
  "missing_from_stripe": [
    "test2@test2.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @Lechucico, ...btw, I've edited this to leave out any keys from the output dict with no values. Hopefully that makes its output more useful (can just compare to `{}` to see if there are any problems).

Comment: I've forgot to add it on the question. I have two customers on elastic.json that must be ignored. How I can ignore these two customers??

Comment: Not sufficiently well-specified to say. (Ignore two *specific* customers? How should the customers to be ignored be separated by the ones to include? Do you just want to count only Stripe and Mongo as sources for customers that are expected to exist everywhere, and not use Elastic for that at all? Etc). I'd suggest asking a separate question, with its own [mcve] (simplifying as much as possible -- if you only need help calculating a different list to assign to `$elastic_ids`, there's no point to including Stripe or Mongo in the question at all) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible?

Yes, there are many ways to achieve both tasks.  You will probably find it easiest to keep track of the three files separately within the jq program.  This too can be done in several ways, but I'd suggest starting with the '--argfile NAME FILENAME' option, one triple for each file.

It's not immediately clear to me what you mean by ascertaining which "customers" are missing, but let me offer this hopefully helpful hint:

If A and B are two JSON arrays, then the expression (A - B) will emit an array containing the items in A that are not in B.

Comment: Can you show me some example? I mean customers that are missing, for example. I have a customer called John on mongoDB and this guy must be on elasticsearch too. I want to know if there are everybody on each storage.  The problem is that each storage has it's own json format.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  This answer was written before [Lechucico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7175708/lechucico) simplified the sample data and clarified the relationships between the objects.  The following may only be of cursory interest since [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy) has provided a good solution to the revised problem.

---

You need to understand your data before you can make progress on this.  You could start with a report,

```
  "__________________________________________________  mongo.json"
, ($mongo[] | {client_id, name})

, "__________________________________________________  elastic.json"
, ($elastic[] | {alias, index})

, "__________________________________________________  stripe.json"
, ($stripe.data[] | {id, object})
```

If the above filter is in `filter.jq` then the command

```
jq -Mnc \
  --argfile mongo mongo.json \
  --argfile elastic elastic.json \
  --argfile stripe stripe.json \
  -f filter.jq
```

produces

```
__________________________________________________  mongo.json
{"client_id":"TEST","name":"Windows Client"}
{"client_id":"TEST2","name":"Linux Client"}
__________________________________________________  elastic.json
{"alias":"living","index":"living_v1"}
{"alias":"reindex","index":"living_v1"}
__________________________________________________  stripe.json
{"id":"cus_BRKuwUx0TS1LPL","object":"customer"}
```

It's pretty clear that these are different types of objects so there may not be an obvious one-to-one relationship between them but if you investigate your actual data and workflow you may be able to discover a more meaningful link.